# grep Exception but exclude specific Exception

Tags: regex, shell, unix, grep

I am currently matching for "Exception" from a file, and output 10 lines before and after using:

> grep -C 10 "[.*Exception"

But now I wish to exclude certain specific Exceptions, say ***AAAException*** and ***BBBException***, how could I do it? It can be done via

> grep -v "AAAException" | grep -C 10 "[.*Exception"

But if within the file, I have ***AAAException*** within 10 lines from some other Exception, that line would not be included in the output, which is not what I want. How can I not match for ***AAAException***, but if it occurred within 10 lines from some other Exception, it will still be included in the output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have `grep -P` you can specify a negative lookbehind assertion.

```
grep -C 10 -P '\[.*(?<!AAA|BBB)Exception'
```

Comment: It basically means "the text before here cannot be".

Comment: It will improve the quality of answer, if you can please expalin this regex you have used.Thanks!

Comment: Could you tell me what `\[` means?

Comment: The backslash makes the next character into a literal; without it, `[` has a special meaning in regex (defines a character class like `[^a-z]`).

Answer (score 0):

If your positive match pattern **Exception** is a word i.e not preceded/followed by other alphabets then you can use word-boundary.

```
$ grep -C 10 '\<NullPointerException\>\|\<SessionTimeoutException\>'
```

Comment: It can be any kind of Exception, say NullPointerException or SessionTimeoutException

Comment: If you have list of +ve *Exception, you can **OR with |**

Comment: I do not get what you mean "OR with |", however at present stage, I have an exclude list instead

Comment: That will work if I have a positive list, but I have a negative list instead. Which means I need to match ALL Exception except for NullPointerException or SessionTimeoutException

Comment: You can't achieve that with plain grep, check @tripleee solution.